# Error while installing WFDB packages : make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/Administrator/wfdb-10.7.0/lib' make: *** [Makefile:307: install] Error 2

Tags: python, cmake, makefile, cygwin, gnu-make

I need to use some applications like rdsamp inside WFDB to read signal files (.dat file records) inside WFDB database .
I followed steps in https://archive.physionet.org/physiotools/wfdb-windows-quick-start.shtml
Documentation says we need to install cygwin to support WFDB package installation .
My system is 64 bit windows machine and I installed cygwin  from http://cygwin.com/setup-x86_64.exe .

Selected below packages while installing cygwin .
from the Devel category: gcc-core, gcc-fortran, make
from the Libs category: libcurl-devel, libexpat-devel
from the Net category: curl

Later from cygwin terminal I downloaded and extracted wfdb database :-

```
curl https://physionet.org/physiotools/wfdb.tar.gz | tar xvz
cd wfdb-10.m.n
```

Then from wfdb-10.m.n directory in cygwin terminal, performed below steps :-

```
./configure

not printing whole output here.. snippet:-
Summary:

wfdb-10.7.0-cygwin is now ready to be compiled using 'gcc'.
The WFDB library will be compiled as a dynamic library with NETFILES
 access via libcurl, and it will be installed in '/usr/local/bin'.
The WFDB library .h files will be installed in '/usr/local/include/wfdb'.
The WFDB applications will be linked to dynamic system libraries, and
 they will be installed in '/usr/local/bin'.
```

```
$ make install
cd lib;      make clean; make install
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/Administrator/wfdb-10.7.0/lib'
rm -f wfdbinit.o annot.o signal.o calib.o wfdbio.o libwfdb.* *.dll *~
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/Administrator/wfdb-10.7.0/lib'
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/Administrator/wfdb-10.7.0/lib'
make clean          # force recompilation since config may have changed
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/Administrator/wfdb-10.7.0/lib'
rm -f wfdbinit.o annot.o signal.o calib.o wfdbio.o libwfdb.* *.dll *~
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/Administrator/wfdb-10.7.0/lib'
make all
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/Administrator/wfdb-10.7.0/lib'
make setup
make[3]: Entering directory '/home/Administrator/wfdb-10.7.0/lib'
sed "s+DBDIR+/usr/local/database+" <wfdblib.h0 >wfdblib.h
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/Administrator/wfdb-10.7.0/lib'
make wfdbinit.o annot.o signal.o calib.o wfdbio.o
make[3]: Entering directory '/home/Administrator/wfdb-10.7.0/lib'
gcc -Wno-implicit -Wformat  -g -O -DWFDB_MAJOR=10 -DWFDB_MINOR=7 -DWFDB_RELEASE=0 -DWFDB_LARGETIME -DNOVALUES_H `curl-config --cflags`  -I/usr/local/include   -c -o wfdbinit.o wfdbinit.c
make[3]: *** [<builtin>: wfdbinit.o] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/Administrator/wfdb-10.7.0/lib'
make[2]: *** [Makefile:240: all] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/Administrator/wfdb-10.7.0/lib'
make[1]: *** [Makefile:246: install] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/Administrator/wfdb-10.7.0/lib'
make: *** [Makefile:307: install] Error 2
```

May I know what is wrong here .

Comment: The **first** error message you got is `make[3]: *** [<builtin>: wfdbinit.o] Error 1`. Probably, the previous gcc invocation (`gcc -Wno-implicit -Wformat ...`) returns non-zero exit code. You may copy-paste this command into the terminal, and run it from the same directory, as you run `make install`.

Comment: Executed gcc command as you said .. It does not print any response/output . 
$ gcc -Wno-implicit -Wformat  -g -O -DWFDB_MAJOR=10 -DWFDB_MINOR=7 -DWFDB_RELEASE=0 -DWFDB_LARGETIME -DNOVALUES_H `curl-config --cflags`  -I/usr/local/include   -c -o wfdbinit.o wfdbinit.c

Administrator@WIN-E255T3IFTGJ ~/wfdb-10.7.0

May I know what is causing

Comment: Does that command actually creates the output file (`wfdbinit.o`)? What is the exit code of that command (`echo $?`)?

Comment: It does not create wfdbinit.o . exit code is 1 . 
 
`Administrator@WIN-E255T3IFTGJ ~/wfdb-10.7.0/lib
$ echo $?
1

Administrator@WIN-E255T3IFTGJ ~/wfdb-10.7.0/lib
$ ls
annot.c  calib.c  COPYING.LIB  ecgcodes.h  ecgmap.h  Makefile  Makefile.top  Makefile.tpl  README  signal.c  wfdb.h  wfdb.h0  wfdbinit.c  wfdbio.c  wfdblib.h  wfdblib.h0
`
"Administrator@WIN-E255T3IFTGJ ~/wfdb-10.7.0/lib
$ pwd
/home/Administrator/wfdb-10.7.0/lib"

Answer (score 0):

the Makefiles have some very strange actions

1. clean during install is a very strange action. Remove it from the various Makefiles
2. replace exestrip with standard strip- Otherwise will try to strip `*.exe.exe`
3. it is installing a copy of `/bin/cygwin1.dll` on `/usr/local`
   Remove it and also `cygz.dll`.
   **It is the cause of the error you see**